# Как добавить возможность скрывать элементы drawer в настройках?

Tags: java, android, android-navigation-drawer

Элементы drawer прописаны в config.java. Как скрывать определенные элементы, если в настройках стоит галочка?
В config.java код такого содержания:

```
public static void configureMenu(SimpleMenu menu, ConfigParser.CallBack callback){
List<NavItem> secondTabs = new ArrayList<NavItem>();
        secondTabs.add(new NavItem("WebView", WebviewFragment.class,new String[]{"http://google.ru"}));
        menu.add("Google", R.drawable.ic_details, secondTabs);
callback.configLoaded(false);
    }
```

В активити SimpleMenu:

```
public class SimpleMenu extends SimpleAbstractMenu {

    public SimpleMenu(Menu menu, MenuItemCallback callback){
        super();
        this.menu = menu;
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    public MenuItem add(String title, int drawable, List<NavItem> action) {
        return add(menu, title, drawable, action);
    }

    public MenuItem add(String title, int drawable, List<NavItem> action, boolean requiresPurchase) {
        return add(menu, title, drawable, action, requiresPurchase);
    }

}
```

В SimpleAbstractMenu:

```
MenuItem item = menu.add(R.id.main_group, Menu.NONE, Menu.NONE, title).setCheckable(true).setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
        callback.menuItemClicked(action, menuItem, requiresPurchase);
        return true;
    }
});
```

В activity_main_drawer.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single" android:id="@+id/main_group">



    </group>

</menu>
```

Comment: Необходимо больше конкретики, какой `drawer` вы используете (стандартный / библиотеку), каким образом элементы подключаются в него. Здесь нет экстрасенсов.

Comment: @zTrap, дополнил сообщение